# Animation not destroying until a Mouse move or screen click

Tags: angular, lottie

I have a animation set when after a API call is complete the Animation plays out and is then destroyed, however the Animation plays out and then remains on screen frozen until I move the mouse or on a Mobile touch the screen:

```
animationLoopCompleted(){
    if (this.apiFinished) {
      this.showMatchingAnimation = false;
      this.lottieAnimation.destroy();
    }
  };
```

Comment: Angular's change detection didn't run? Call `dedectChanges()` with `ChangeDetectorRef` https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef or use `*ngIf` binded to `this.showMatchingAnimation`.

Comment: I've a min-height from the CSS on the container this was on and that has done some of the work, however it seems to be cutting the top 20px off the browser screen until I move the mouse